# Android Studio is giving me a error in name saying it has to be a "throwable tr" in log.v . Can someone explain me why

Tags: android

Android Studio is giving me a error in 'name' saying it has to be a 
"throwable tr" in log.v . Can someone explain me why?

Log.v("MainActivity", "Name: ",name);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Log Class documentation:

- @param tag Used to identify the source of a log message. 
         It usually identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs.
- @param msg The message you would like logged.
- @param tr An    exception to log

  ```
   public static int v(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
      return printlns(LOG_ID_MAIN, VERBOSE, tag, msg, tr);
    }
  ```

  -- Simply use this method :

  ```
  Log.v("MainActivity", String.format("Name : %s",  name));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the third argument is a type of `Throwable`.

As per the documentation, method syntax is:

```
public static int v (String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)
```

[Link to documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#v(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable))

If you want to print `name`, you can write like this:

```
Log.v("MainActivity", String.format("Name : %s", name));
```